# Insert all dates between start and end date into table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

let's say i have 2 table

First one is "Orders"

```
Select * from Orders
```

give me this results.

```
 Order_ID   Date_Start          Date_End                                   Order_Name
2059    2020-11-13 00:00:00.000 2020-11-14 00:00:00.000             order1
2060    2020-12-12 00:00:00.000 2020-12-22 00:00:00.000             order2
```

and second table say it "Dates"

This is desired results for Dates table.i need to insert dates between two dates to that table for each order ID.

```
Date                    Type1   Type2   Type3   Type4   Type5   Order_ID
2020-11-13 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2059
2020-11-14 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2059
```

i hope this is more clear now.

Comment: Codeproject has a lot of good examples.  Not sure if you want to use a calendar or a list view.  See following : ClockHubClient

Answer (score 2):

Actually quite simple using OVER/PARTITION and then dateadd().

First, we need to get however many records you want in your final list of records.  To do this, pick any table that has at least as many rows as you want.  Could be an employee table, customers, orders, whatever.  For your example, as long as it had 14 days.  From that, lets just create a temp result set giving you a simple run of numbers 1 through whatever... 10,   14,   127, whatever, as long as the table has that many records.

Now, the partition by order by is part of the trick.  You can't partition by constants, but you CAN do based on an equation.  So, pick the "ID" column of whatever table and multiply by 0 will always give you 0.  So your partitioning will group all values with an equated value of 0... Tricky huh...  So now, all the records fall into this one group and get assigned a row number within that group.  Finish that off with a "TOP 14", and you get your 14 records to start your list basis.

```
SELECT top 10
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SomeTableID * 0 order by SomeTableID * 0) AS "MyRow"
    FROM 
        SomeTable
```

So now, I have a result set with 10 rows in it with the values running from 1 to 10.

Now, lets build the dates.  As long as you are building consecutively, such as per day, per month, per year, or whatever pattern, use one date as your baseline and keep adding.  In the sample below, I am using the current date and just keep adding 1 month, but again, you can do for days, weeks, whatever.

```
select
      dateadd( month, Counter.MyRow, convert( date, getdate() )) ListOfDates
   from
      ( SELECT top 10 ROW_NUMBER() 
              OVER(PARTITION BY SomeTableID * 0 order by SomeTableID * 0) AS "MyRow"
           FROM SomeTable ) Counter
```

So, in the above example, it will return 10 rows starting with today and generate

```
2020-11-20
2020-12-20
2021-01-20
...
2021-08-20
```

FOLLOW-UP.

Your query is failing because you are explicitly concatenating strings to build your command... BAD technique.  You should parameterize your queries.  Build a SQL Command object, add parameters, and THEN call your fill.

```
var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("", con);
sqlcmd.CommandText = 
@"WITH theDates AS 
(
   SELECT @parmStartDate as theDate
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, theDate)
      FROM theDates
      WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, theDate) <= @parmEndDate
)

SELECT theDate
   FROM theDates
   OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)";


sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmStartDate", dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[2] );
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmEndDate", dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[3] );

var ds = new DataSet();
var dtbl2 = new DataTable();
// pass the pre-formatted and parameterized query command to the SQL Data Adapter
var sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
```

Comment: well i really appreciate the afford u took that's really complicated to me but i update my question

Comment: @KutayYorgun, interesting find of code.  Updated answer to show correction for you.  You should parameterize the query with actual date/time fields.  Don't try to do by concatenating strings.  You have much harder time controlling data conversion types.  Especially with strings that may have an actual 'single quote' within it that would otherwise terminate unexpectedly for you.

Comment: @KutayYorgun, it would also be good to know where your original finding of that code snippet came from applying the recursion technique.  Very nice to know.  Please edit your original post with source if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sql to build a dynamic date range table. You will need to customize it for your needs in the /* replace with your column after join */ and /* Join your table sections */

```
/*
script to build table with dynamic columns
*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempDateRange
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #dateRangeTable

DECLARE @StartDate datetime = DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE()), 
@EndDate datetime = GETDATE()

/*
Generate date range table
*/
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) AS [Date],
UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate)), 3)) AS [MonthShort],
MONTH( DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate)) AS [Month],
YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate)) AS [Year],
CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate)), 3)), '-', YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate))) AS MonthYear
INTO #tempDateRange
FROM    ( SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)) ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n AS Nbr
            FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
                 (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
                 (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) hundreds(n),
                 (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thousands(n)
            WHERE ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n BETWEEN 1 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
            ORDER BY 1
        ) nbrs
WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)

/*
Generate columns for date range
*/
DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @columns+=QUOTENAME(convert(nvarchar(10), Date, 120)) + ' NVARCHAR(10),' 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Date, [Month], [Year] FROM #tempDateRange
) x
ORDER BY x.[Year], x.[Month]
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @sql = '

INSERT #dateRangeTable
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT a.TestData AS Data, /* replace with your column after join */
    convert(nvarchar(10), Date, 120) AS [Date]
    FROM #tempDateRange [date]
    /* Join your table */
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT ''start test'' AS TestData,  CAST('''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @StartDate)+''' AS DATE) AS TargetDate
        UNION 
        SELECT ''end test'' AS TestData,  CAST('''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, -1, @EndDate))+''' AS DATE) AS TargetDate
    ) AS a ON CAST(a.TargetDate AS DATE) = CAST(date.[date] AS DATE)
    WHERE [date].[Date] BETWEEN CAST('''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @StartDate)+''' AS DATE) AND CAST('''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @EndDate)+''' AS DATE)
) o
PIVOT(
    MAX(Data)
    FOR [Date] IN ('+ REPLACE(@columns, 'NVARCHAR(10)', '') +')
) AS pivot_table;
'


SET @sql = N'
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #dateRangeTable
CREATE TABLE #dateRangeTable('+@columns+')
' + 
@sql 
+ N'
SELECT * FROM #dateRangeTable
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #dateRangeTable
'
PRINT (@sql)
--EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```